# How to let class have file scope?

Tags: c++

### Question

I have a class, I want it have a file scope. Such as the static function in cpp file.

```
static void myFun();
static void myFun()
{

}
```

#### Why I want this?

I have many test file, such as `test_A.cpp, test_B.cpp, test_C.cpp`.

Each cpp file may contain the class `X` for it self. `X` is used for test stub, or mocker class.

If a executable file have contain these cpp files, the class `X` is multiple defined and it is ambigous.

So I wonder is there any way to let the class X have file scope.

I know we can avoid thses problem by add namespace to cover `X` or rename class `X` into `X_A`, `X_B`, `X_C` is OK. But it looks verbose.

If a class can have file scope, it is more elagent.

Any suggestions? Thanks for your time.